# What rules or guidance should be followed assigning busses to I/O banks in Xilinx Spartan FPGAs?

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I am modifying a Spartan 6 project to upgrade several external interfaces from 16 to 32 bit data paths. I have it in mind that all signals in a data or address bus should be assigned to one I/O bank (but different busses can be on different banks). I have searched (mostly the Xilinx documentation) for guidance on this question, but failed to find a suitable answer. Please advise which of these applies, and why.

- All signals in a bus should be on one I/O bank
- Split address or data busses across more that one bank to reduce simultaneous switching loads
- It doesn't matter, as long as the voltages are compatible.

In my case, all the I/O is the same voltage and no differential drivers or receivers are required.

I am expecting to be guided to the first answer to use a local common clock for all signals in the bus, but I cannot find any information to justify that expectation.

Comment: You're asking a non-specific question that is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. Have you considered Xilinx documentation (e.g. Xilinx IO Pin Planning Tutorial: PlanAhead Design Tool (UG674), Vivado Design Suite Tutorial: I/O and Clock Planning (UG935)).

Comment: [AR# 34313 Spartan-6 I/O Banking Rules - Output I/O Standard Restrictions](https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/34313.html) which also tells us [Spartan-6 FPGA SelectIO Resources User Guide UG381](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug381.pdf) "should be used as the absolute reference for banking rules".

Comment: It's not a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) generally covering a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or  software tools commonly used by programmers; and is not  a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development and you're soliciting opinions. If you can't find any vendor rules there aren't any. Notice Spartan 6 has more I/O guidelines than any earlier device family.